# Show first item in RecyclerView as soon as it becomes available

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there any way to show `RecyclerView` item as soon as at least one item becomes available?

Like I am downloading list of objects from network and only displayed when complete data becomes populated in list (list then passed to adapter) and then I have to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` to show in `RecyclerView`.

[Android working with RecyclerView](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/). Like this tutorial, say I am downloading list of movies from network and there are thousands of movies.

Do I need to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` in my `onProgressUpdate(...)` in my `AsyncTask`?

Comment: You can call ```notifyDatasetChanged()``` in your ```onProgressUpdate(...)```.

Comment: I am using retrofit library